# What is the efficient way to highlight the selected page number?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css

I have numbers in `<li>` in a html page, the numbers represent the number of pages:

```
<ol id="numbers">

     <li class="idx">1</li>
     <li class="idx">2</li>
      ...
      ...
     <li class="idx">n</li>                         
</ol>
```

The number of pages are dynamical, how to use jQuery to bold the page number text which is clicked, while keep other page number texts in default font style? Do I must use a for loop to change the unselected one to default style when there is a new page number selected?

Comment: Just add a class to the clicked `li` and remove it from the previous selected `li` (with that class). No, you don't need loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qE3Qm/2/

Better solution is to have `.active` css class with styles for active page. And set it on click:

```
$('#numbers li').click(function() {
    $('#numbers li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Why not `$('#numbers .active').removeClass('active')` ? No need to select all `li`s.

Comment: Uhm, that is not what I meant... you have to add the click handler to all `li`s (or use event delegation).

Comment: Sorry, added in wrong place. in jsfiddle everything is correct. Thanks for you attention :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  simple [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function , and add a bold style to them.

```
<style>
  .highlight {font-weight:bold; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<body>
  <p class="blue">Click to toggle</p>
  <p class="blue highlight">highlight</p>
  <p class="blue">on these</p>
  <p class="blue">paragraphs</p>
<script>
    $("p").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
</script>
</body>
```

But my version just highlight the currently  selected li, and leave otheher list items  in a  previous status, so if that one was selected previously this code doesn't change the previous status. If you need to  highlight only one item, then the best way  to remove the bold style from all list items, and then add a bold style to the currently selected item, as everybody recommended previously.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the existence of a class `.bold` which contains your style:

```
$("#number li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("bold").siblings().removeClass("bold");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

SCRIPT:

```
$('ol#numbers li.idx').click(function(){
    $('ol#numbers li.idx').removeClass('bolt-style');
    $(this).addClass('bolt-style');
});
```

CSS:

```
.bolt-style
{
    font-weight:bold;  
}
```

See an example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zaW2Q](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zaW2Q/3/)